# jsf page could not be restored

Tags: java, jsf, viewexpiredexception

I get this error when I click on a `selectBooleanCheckBox`. What should I do?

```
10:36:03,105 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/snsEJBwm].[Faces Servlet]] Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception: javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: viewId:/pages/report.jsf - View /pages/report.jsf could not be restored.
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:195) [:2.0.3-]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97) [:2.0.3-]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:107) [:2.0.3-]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:114) [:2.0.3-]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:308) [:2.0.3-]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:324) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79) [:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:274) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:67) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:274) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:181) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.event(CatalinaContext.java:285) [:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.invoke(CatalinaContext.java:261) [:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:88) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:100) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.request.ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.invoke(ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.java:53) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:362) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:654) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:951) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [:1.6.0_18]
```

Comment: Is this happening immediately after the page is rendered ? Or you wait a while and you get this exception ? also what is your javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD client or server ?

Comment: Please post **the smallest possible** XHTML file and backing bean code which still reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it happens to me when I : load the page, then deploy a modification on the server, and then refresh the page. Is it what you are doing?

Answer (score 0):

Do you see the exception consistently? Usually it appears in the logs when you click on the UI but the HttpSession expires.